# React navigation - Render Custom Header Inside the Screen View

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using React Navigation, I would like to pass a custom header component using `header` option in `navigationOptions`.

The problem is that the header is rendered outside of the screens view. In my case I want it to be part of the screen's `ScrollView`, and scroll up along with the screen (not stay sticky on the top).

I've tried setting `header` to `null` in `navigationOptions`, and manually put the header component inside the screen's `ScrollView`, but this way I can't access the `headerProps` that are passed to the header component when using the [`header`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#header) option. The `headerProps` are necessary to access things like the previous scene etc.

Any solution for this?

Comment: what are the header props that you need to pass? can you throw some light?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay updated. thanks

Comment: hmm, kinda hacky but you can assigned headerprops to a variable and then export it. and finally import it in your scrollview component. lemme know if that works for you. i'll update it with an answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

- Hide header from **react-navigation** and add your header in the screen component, inside ScrollView:

  ```js
  const SignedOut = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignIn,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: () => null,
        },
      },
  });
  ```

  `SignIn screen`:

  ```js
  class SignIn extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
         <! -- add header for screen and content -->
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
  }
  export default SignIn;
  ```

In this way you can render a custom header component inside your ScrollView.